# Navigation for dependent pages

Tags: navigation, sidebar

I'm working on a location analysis dashboard. There are three main sections that are somewhat but not really related and somewhat but not really in a hierarchical system.

There's the **main page**. A overview of all locations (around 20) in a table.

There's a location **details page**. That's the biggest of sections it features a sidebar with submenus. The user gets to the detail page by clicking on a row inside the overview-table.

There's a location **comparison page**. Where two or more locations can be compared. The comparison opens by selecting multiple locations inside the table and then clicking on 'compare'.

I'm worried that the navigation structure is not clear enough as two of the sections only become apparend when interacting with the table. I was thinking about creating a sidebar that features the items: *Overview*, *Details* and *Comparison* but that doesn't really make sense because the two sections *Details* and *Comparison* depend on a selection made in *Overview*

Are there any best practices to navigate an UI like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recommend sitting down with a little paper and mapping out how you think people want to use all of this information.

Think about some of the following questions and try to come up with more.

- What exactly do people want to do? (not just with your site, but in general, are they looking for a new place to live? Are they trying to find security issues around the globe?)
- What makes someone want to navigate to a details page from the main page?
- What is the purpose of comparing two or more locations?

It sounds like there are similar proxies in the way people search for products like cameras or cars. I would recommend checking out some sites for a little inspiration.